# recreate db of EF asp.net core project

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have messed up my migrations and decided to remove all files in the migrations folder. I have also deleted the DB that was created by EF.

Unfortunately now when I run the following commands:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef database update
```

The only table being created is the MigrationsHistory table for EF, none of my tables are being created.

What do I need to do to start from scratch so that all my tables are created in the db from my models in code?

Comment: have you deleted all the data migrated scripts ?

Comment: In previous versions of EF we had to use `-force` flag to re-create the initial migration. Maybe there is something similar in the .Net Core world...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working simple by removing the Migrations folder and not just the migration files inside the folder.

That did the trick for me!

:)